# Powershell SQL cluster resource check

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cluster-computing

I have created the below in order to make check for active node based on the "SQL Server Availability Group". However, for some reason it does not work. The file is created and it contains the info needed. When I debug it via ISE, the variables are correctly read but each time I get the else response.

```
$date=get-date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
$thisNode = Get-Content env:COMPUTERNAME
$random=get-random -maximum 1000
$trace_dir="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
$trace_file="$trace_dir\trace_$date`_$random.txt"
Get-ClusterResource | where-object {$_.ResourceType -like "SQL Server Availability Group"} | format-list * >> $trace_file
$owner=Select-String -path $trace_file -pattern 'OwnerNode' | Out-String

IF($owner -contains $thisNode){ echo "primary" >> trace_file}

ELSE { echo "slave" >> trace_file}
```

The random number is used in order to create different file each time the script is executed.
Things I tried:

1. Format further the output using format-list -Property OwnerNode. It gets only the line needed but still gives false.
2. Sleep between the if clause and variable.
3. Remove the variables that are not needed ( ex. thisNode with the actual name).
4. Check if the output is ASCII or something wrong with the output, same.
5. I am aware that I can get the correct response using "Get-Content $traceFile | Select-String -Pattern $env:COMPUTERNAME" but I want to know why the above is not working.

Comment: Reading your script, it looks like your intent is to identify whether the current host is the owner of an availability group. For context, why are you dumping both the output from `Get-ClusterResource` and the determination of the server's current role to a file (let alone the same file)?

Comment: This is a demand from DBAs.